# How can I get Facebook like/share count on an external page (i.e. outside of Facebook) now that Graph API has changed?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Now that the Facebook Graph API has changed (and a lot of old functionality is dead...) is it possible now to easily visit graph.facebook.com (or another FB URL) and input the external site I want to look up the Facebook like count/share count on?

I used to use the below method to easily find this information, but this function appears to be dead with the API change.  How can we easily find this info now?  The most I can get is the share count by tacking the research URL to the end of graph.facebook.com, but I want to know like count as well.

Old method that worked great:
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=URLHERE

New method that hardly gives me info:
https://graph.facebook.com/URLHERE

I had this question marked as a duplicate of a question asked in 2015.  That question and its answers are no longer valid, as the REST API has deprecated and none of the answers on questions from prior to July 2016 work anymore!

Bless this mess in advance if you have any thoughts/solutions re: this!

Comment: I opened a ticket with Facebook regarding this issue.  It seems everyone has the same issue but there are no answers.  I will update you if I get a resolution.  FYI it looks like the current API lumps shares, likes, and comments into one sum and counts them all as "shares".

Comment: Ticket was closed and merged with this one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/748651458568287/